# How to safely return generic objects

Tags: java, generics

I'm doing some experiments, trying to understand the issues surrounding returning generics.  The following program runs without error and prints "FOO gets BAR" at the end.  Can anyone explain why?  The GetMap() member has unsafely cast a HashMap<Integer,Integer> to a Map<K,V>, which in the test case is a Map<String,String>.  All my reading suggests I should get a ClassCastException, but I'm not getting one.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GenericTrial
{
 public static <K,V> Map<K,V> GetMap()
 { 
  return (Map<K,V>)new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
 }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     try
     {
      Map<String,String> m = GetMap();
      m.put("FOO", "BAR");
      System.out.println("FOO gets " + m.get("FOO"));
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
      System.out.println("Got exception");
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a compile warning on line return (Map<K,V>)new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); ?

Comment: Oh yes.  I could override it, obviously, but that's not the point of the experiment.

Comment: That warning told you that you are effectively violating the (compile-time) generic type system.  Why are you surprised that violating the type system leads to results like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of Java's [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure), there is no difference at runtime between a `Map<K, V>` and a `Map<T, U>`.

Generic types are a purely compile-time concept.

Comment: I've been reading about type erasure and its consequences; that's what I'm trying to understand.  I have made the code above so that it compiles with no problem by means of my (unsafe) type case... but I thought a run-time error would ensue.  Instead I not only see no runtime error, I also see no crash or other ill behaviour when I start stuffing strings into an integer map.  How can this be?

Comment: Because a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` is really just a `HashMap` -- it can contain any kind of element, thanks to type erasure.  See my answer.

Comment: OK, I think this is the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: I've been reading on the web about means of making my GetMap() member safe.  Obviously if I could simply look at the types represented by K and V, there'd be no problem.  There doesn't seem to be a clear answer to this -- I've seen (but not completely understood) some claims that this can be done, perhaps using Type Tokens (see http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Using_TypeTokens_to_retrieve_generic_parameters).

Comment: @vw-register: Is what you want a generic method that returns a new `Map<K, V>`? If so, just have it return `new HashMap<K, V>()`.

Answer (score 3):

Java generics use type erasure, which is a compile-time construct.  The line:

```
return (Map<K,V>)new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

Will be compiled as this:

```
return (Map)new HashMap();
```

You would get an exception in C#, because generic information exists at runtime and is properly verified.

(This is one of the many reasons why I don't use Java for anything anymore.)

Comment: Because you need the runtime to tell you how to use your objects?

Comment: @Falmarri Yes, of course, you're right. We should all use assembly. Languages shouldn't try to make things safer or easier for developers and runtimes shouldn't try to enforce their type system.

Comment: In practice, this isn't really a big deal as long as you don't do obviously stupid things (that produce warnings, mind you) like using raw types or casting generic types to other generic types that are clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is working is because you aren't putting anything in the `Map<Integer, Integer>` before returning it. Since the `Map` doesn't know what types it's supposed to contain at runtime (due to erasure), it accepts a `String` to `String` mapping just fine when it runs. Where you'd have a problem is if you did this:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> getMap() {
  Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  map.put(1, 1);
  return (Map<K, V>) map;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, String> map = getMap();
  for (String key : map.keySet()) { // ClassCastException
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite right.  The exception arises because you try to cast `Integer` to `String`, not because you casted a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: In fact I did this very thing, and I certainly did get an exception.

Comment: @cdhowie: Nowhere did I suggest that the exception was due to casting `Map<Integer, Integer>` to `Map<String, String>`. That said, the exception would have been prevented at compile time if the `getMap()` method didn't do something that's obviously illegal (casting a `Map` of a specific type to a `Map` of any arbitrary type the of the caller's choosing).

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd get back and post a few things I've learned in the course of investigating this.  I now know of a couple ways to (sort of, partially) work around type-erasure.

One is discussed here: "[Using TypeTokens to retrieve generic parameters](http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Using_TypeTokens_to_retrieve_generic_parameters)".  I didn't follow this up in detail; the gist, as I understand it, is that *at the time of construction* of an instance of a generic object, e.g., LinkedList<String>, information about the generic type (String) has not yet been erased, and can be captured and saved for future reference.  This didn't really apply to my needs.

What I was needing was a way to specify a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public <T> void setList(List<T> list, ...);
    public <T> List<T> getList(...);
    public <T> void setSet(Set<T> set, ...);
    public <T> Set<T> getSet(...);
    public <K,V> void setMap(Map<K,V> map, ...);
    public <K,V> Map<K,V> getMap(...);
}
```

such that I can say things like:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = fooInstance.getMap(...);
otherFooInstance.setMap(map);
```

where T, K and V could be of any type, and -- since I'm creating an interface specifically for a customer to use -- do it all safely.  As a simplification, I'm willing that type T be limited to non-generic types -- no List<Map<String,Set<Integer>>,Float> contraptions.

The dodge I came up with is only a partial success:

For setXXXX(), I have to pass in an instance of the collection class.  Type erasure prevents me from getting the type of the list from the collection itself, but I *can* get the types of the members of the collection.  The following routine, for example, can be passed a List or Set:

```
<T> Type GetType(Collection<T> c) {
    Type t = null;
    if (!c.isEmpty()) {
        t = c.iterator().next().getClass();
    }
    return t;
}
```

and a Map can be passed to this:

```
<K,V> Type[] GetTypes(Map<K,V> m) { 
    Type[] t = null;
    if (!m.isEmpty()) {
        Map.Entry<K,V> entry = m.entrySet().iterator().next();
        t = new Type[]{ entry.getKey().getClass(), 
                       entry.getValue().getClass() };
    }
    return t;
}
```

Of course, if the collection instance contain no entries, this gimmick fails... but in that case there's nothing that needs to be done anyway.  This part isn't too bad.

On the getXXXX() side, things are less satisfactory.  The best thing I've come up with is simply to pass in the collection Type I want to have returned.

```
Set<String> set = fooInstance.getSet(String.class);
```

For Maps I provided two methods:

```
Map<String,Long> map = fooInstance.getmap(String.class, Long.class);
Map<String,Long> map = fooInstance.getmap(new Type[]{String.class, Long.class});
```

Obviously, the getXXXX() and setXXXX() functions, since they know what types I'm expecting, can either deal with type or they can't, in which case they return an error value or throw an exception.

The problem with this, however, is that it isn't safe.  I can write:

```
Set<String> set = fooInstance.getSet(String.class);
Set<Integer> otherSet = fooInstance.getSet(String.class);
```

and not get an exception.  I *could* require that the collection object to be returned be passed in to the getXXXX() function... and that it be populated, so I can figure out what types it contains... but yuk.

Anybody know a better solution?